# Storing files on client\harddrive from browser\java applet

Tags: applet, certificate

(How) is it possible to let the user store a file (via save file dialog) on the local harddrive via a java applet?

Is there any workarounds for this or do I have to apply for some sort of certificate somewhere?

For example, when printing from a Java Applet the user gets a dialog asking for permission, is it possible to do something similair in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to signe your applet http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html, or you can use the WebStart technology.